# Display image with format .mat in OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, mat-file

I am trying to replicate a code taht I did in MATLAB to Python, using OpenCV.
I have an image with .mat format that I managed to load, however I cannot displayed it using cv2.imshow(), since it does not supports it.
So does anyone know how I can visualize my image??

```
#Load image
import scipy.io as sio 

matimage='img1.mat'
img = sio.loadmat(matimage)
cv2.imshow('Image', img)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: According to the documentation of [`scipy.io.loadmat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html): "*Returns:* ... dictionary with variable names as keys, and loaded matrices as values." | So no, you can't pass that dictionary to `cv2.imshow` an expect it to work. What variables does the mat file (and therefore the loaded dictionary you misnamed `img`) contain?

Comment: I solved it using:

"name = sio.loadmat('img1', appendmat=True)
a = name['img1']"